# Installation at 51% Module 'Magento_Theme' Error in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, module, error, installation

Magento 2 Installation error at 51%.

I am having an issue installing Magento 2.
I followed every step and everything went fine until installation.The installation stops at 66%
I tried to find a solution for this issue online but so far, I didn't.

Some help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Here is the console log :

```
Module 'Magento_Theme':
    [ERROR] InvalidArgumentException: Wrong file in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php:64 Stack trace:
    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\magento\framework\Image.php(55): Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2->open('C:/xampp/htdocs...')
    #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\magento\framework\Image.php(36): Magento\Framework\Image->open()
    #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(121): Magento\Framework\Image->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2), 'C:/xampp/htdocs...')
    #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
    #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
    #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\magento\framework\Image\Factory.php(47): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
    #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\magento\framework\View\Design\Theme\Image.php(127): Magento\Framework\Image\Factory->create('C:/xampp/htdocs...')
    #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\magento\module-theme\Model\Theme\Registration.php(135): Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\Image->createPreviewImage('C:/xampp/htdocs...')
    #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\magento\module-theme\Model\Theme\Registration.php(114): Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Registration->_savePreviewImage(Object(Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Data))
    #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\magento\module-theme\Model\Theme\Registration.php(73): Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Registration->_registerThemeRecursively(Object(Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Data))
    #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\magento\module-theme\Setup\Patch\Data\RegisterThemes.php(47): Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Registration->register()
    #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier.php(162): Magento\Theme\Setup\Patch\Data\RegisterThemes->apply()
    #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(1023): Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier->applyDataPatch('Magento_Theme')
    #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(890): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data', Array) #14 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures(Array)
    #15 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(371): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #16 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
    #17 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(83): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
    #18 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(321): Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #19 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(178): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #20 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(115): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #21 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(117): Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
    #22 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(321): Laminas\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #23 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(178): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #24 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Application.php(339): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #25 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\setup\index.php(39): Laminas\Mvc\Application->run() #26 {main} Next Magento\Framework\Setup\Exception: Unable to apply data patch Magento\Theme\Setup\Patch\Data\RegisterThemes for module Magento_Theme. Original exception message: Wrong file in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier.php:170 Stack trace:
    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(1023): Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier->applyDataPatch('Magento_Theme')
    #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(890): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data', Array) #2 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures(Array)
    #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(371): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
    #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(83): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
    #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(321): Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(178): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(115): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(117): Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
    #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(321): Laminas\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent))
    #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(178): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
    #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Application.php(339): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\setup\index.php(39): Laminas\Mvc\Application->run() #14 {main}
```

Comment: You should not use windows, also not for developing, it is not supported. Install magento via docker.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to perfact solution please edit below function on line no 96 follow this-
vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php--

```
private function validateURLScheme(string $filename) : bool
  {
      $allowed_schemes = ['ftp', 'ftps', 'http', 'https'];
      $url = parse_url($filename);
      if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes) && !file_exists($filename)) {
          return false;
      }

      return true;
  }
```

more info please refer below github url https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28055

Comment: thank you. it works!!!!

Comment: thank you it works for me too. :)

Comment: For those of you coming for Magento 2.4.6, this answer is still relevant. I just fixed this on 2.4.6.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  Found a workaround on GitHub.  Installed 100%.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28055

Answer (score 0):

Yon can replace this function `validateURLScheme` in below file with mine one.

File name: \vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php

```
    private function validateURLScheme(string $filename) : bool
    {
       $allowed_schemes = ['ftp', 'ftps', 'http', 'https'];
       $url = parse_url($filename);
       if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes) && !file_exists($filename) && strlen($url['scheme']) > 1) {
       return false;
    }

    return true;
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

File name: `\lib\internal\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php`

```
private function validateURLScheme(string $filename) 
{
    if(!file_exists($filename)) { // if file not exist
        $allowed_schemes = ['ftp', 'ftps', 'http', 'https'];
        $url = parse_url($filename);
        if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

It works 100%